# <router-outlet> isn't substituted by component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

i have built an angular2 Tabs-Component and i want to do routing due to the current selected tab.

This is my try:

```
@Routes([
    { path: '/:title', component: TabsComponent }
])
@Component({
    selector: 'customer-app',
    directives: [TabsComponent, Tab, ... ,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    //providers: [TabsComponent],
    template: `
        <router-outlet>
            <tab title="Test 1">
                ...
            </tab>
            <tab title="Test 2">
                ...
            </tab>
        </router-outlet>
    `
})
export class CustomerComponent{}
```

When running this, i get the error

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in ./CustomerComponent
>   class CustomerComponent - inline template:2:12 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No
>   provider for TabsComponent!

So i added @Injectable() to TabsComponent and listet it in the providers property array (the commented line in the code).

NOW, this runs without any error, but  isn't substituted by TabsComponent . (tabs are not shown, in the resulting html there is no `<tabs></tabs>` but still `<router-outlet> <tab></tab> ... </router-outlet>`)

How can i achieve that a TabsComponent is instantiated AND added as a Component in the resulting HTML ?

Comment: Do you have `TabsComponent` in the same file as `CustomerComponent`?

Comment: The error can't be clearer: make sure you have TabComponent properly imported and available.

Comment: No, i have not - and i would not like it, too.

Comment: Having the classes in the same file was not a suggestion or proposed solution, just a try to narrow down possible causes.

Comment: Additionally: At a first sight i had expected not to need a provider for TabsComponent at all since @Routes() does that. Am i wrong ?

Comment: I'm totally confused with your code. is it `@Route` or `@RouteConfig`? Where do you have `name` property? This code looks improper to me.

Comment: It's @Routes(), because @RouteConfig() was replaced since angular2 RC.

Answer (score 1):

Now I see that I missunderstood routing at two points:
1) a child component needs a parent path
2) 's content children are just thrown away

Comment: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` is just a placeholder to where the router adds routed components. It is not supposed to have HTML content.